# Find 2 points in a normal distribution with these given properties

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I would like to find a and b.

[image]

How should I code this in Mathematica? What I did wrong?

```
μ = 10;
σ = 2;
\[ScriptCapitalD] = PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], x];
 Plot[\[ScriptCapitalD], {x, -10, 20}]
 NSolve[{Abs[μ - a] == Abs[μ - b], 0.9 == NProbability[b > x > a, x \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalD]]}, {a, b}]
```

Comment: Define your distribution without `PDF` and try `FindRoot`. Also, you might take advantage of the symmetry of your distribution around the mean.

Comment: @b. gateaux I tried what you said, but I didn't get any answer: 

\[Mu] = 10;
\[Sigma] = 2;
\[ScriptCapitalD] = NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]
Plot[\[ScriptCapitalD], {x, -10, 20}]
FindRoot[{Abs[\[Mu] - a] == Abs[\[Mu] - b], 0.9 == NProbability[b > x > a, x \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalD]]}, {a, b}]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
m = 10; 
s = 2; 
dist = NormalDistribution[m, s]; 

sol1 = FindRoot[{
   Abs[m - a] == Abs[m - b], 
   0.9 == Probability[b > x > a, 
           Distributed[x, dist]]}, 
     {{a, m - s}, {b, m + s}}]
```

> {a -> 6.71029, b -> 13.2897}

```
sol2 = FindRoot[{
   Abs[m - a] == Abs[m - b], 
   0.9 == CDF[dist, b] - CDF[dist, a]}, 
     {{a, m - s}, {b, m + s}}]
```

> {a -> 6.71029, b -> 13.2897}

```
sol3 = {a -> (m - c), b -> (m + c)} /.
   NSolve[
     CDF[dist, m + c] - CDF[dist, m - c] == 9/10,
     c, Reals][[1]] // Quiet
```

> {a -> 6.71029, b -> 13.2897}

Comment: Why did you use this?

{a, m - s}, {b, m + s}

Comment: `FindRoot` needs starting estimates for the variables (`a` and `b`). Estimate for `a` should be below the mean and estimate for `b` should be above the mean. One standard deviation is a sufficient offset from the mean for each.

Answer (score 4):

```
μ = 10;
σ = 2;
p=.9;

Quantile[NormalDistribution[μ, σ],{1-(1+p)/2,(1+p)/2}]
(* {6.71029,13.2897} *)
```

or

```
InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ],{1-(1+p)/2,(1+p)/2}]
(* {6.71029,13.2897} *)
```

Comment: I didn't know that Mathematica has InverseCDF.

Comment: Please tell me why did you use {1-(1+p)/2,(1+p)/2} ?

Comment: @DSaad, as noted by David, the quantiles `{.05, .95}` form an interval symmetric around the mean with total probability `.90`. i.e., the interval bounded by the quantiles `{1-(1+p)/2, (1+p)/2}` has total mass `p`.

Answer (score 1):

The integral is symmetric with respect to mu.  So integrate from mu to a and set it to .9/2:

```
Solve[Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[10, 2], x], {x, 10, a}] == .45, a]
```

{{a -> 13.2897}}

Then b -> 6.7103.